# Loading Big Data on Python

Tags: python, file, bigdata

I'm fairly new to data-science and barely started using python roughly about two months ago.  I've been trying to do a Kaggle competition for fun (catsVsDogs) to try to learn things along the way.  However I'm stopped at the very first step. The problem is that there is a training set, which contains about 25000 .jpg images of cats and dogs and the total directory is approximately 800 MB in size. Whenever I try to load the directory into python and save all the images in a matrix (say we have 100 of (300,200) size images, I would like to save them in a matrix of 100*(60000) size)  I get either a memory error or the system just stops processing.  I'm using canopy on a mac.
I've been trying to read a lot on the internet and find out how people deal with these big images, but it has been a week and I still couldn't find any good source. I would highly appreciate it if somebody helped me out or would just send me a link that describes the situations.
here's the link for Kaggle Competition (you can see there is no prizes involved and it's just for the sake of learning):
https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data

The question is how do I manage to load this big dataset into python using canopy and start training a Neural Network. Or generally how do I deal with big datasets on a single computer without memory error.

Comment: The question is how do I manage to load this big dataset into python using canopy and start training a Neural Network. Or generally how do I deal with big datasets on a single computer without memory error.

Comment: Please put that into the original question by using the edit button.

Comment: Using canopy might be cheating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making an index of items that you wish to read (directory listing).  Next read just the first item, train using just that item, remove that item from memory, move on to the next item, and repeat.  You shouldn't need to have more then a few in memory at any given time.